# Determining total frames in GROMACS trajectory

Tags: dataset

I produced 4 replicate trajectories in GROMACS, and am trying to summarize into a single value, hydrogen bond data from the 4 individual runs.  Because each run was simulated for a different duration and hence have a different number of total frames, I am having trouble normalizing each raw-data replicate (between 0 and 1) before averaging to a single value.  Using "gmx check -f file.xtc" seems to give a readout of the total number of frames, but some data-points are greater than 1 when divided.  Is there a more efficient way to return the total number of frames? (image of output attached)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2rRe.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use some bash script to automate the process. I am in no way an expert in bash. But you can try to do this.

```
gmx check -f file.xtc &> log
grep 'Step' log
```

This will save all Gromacs output it a file called log and grab line containing the keyword 'Step'.